# Python - Print a value from sequential lists

Tags: python

In python I have lists with sequential names, (`list1`, `list2`, `list3`, `list4`, etc.) and an integer variable `n`.

I want to print the second value of a list depending on `n`.
If `n == 3` then print the second value of `list3`.

Comment: do you have a list of these lists?

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Show [mre], incl. sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an basic example:

```py
names = [
    ["john", "smith", "jovi"],
    ["tom", "alexander", "hanks"],
    ["mariah", "carey", "vincent"],
]

def print_second_name(names_lists, n):
     second_item_idx = 1
     # index minus 1 as you want to start from 1 instead of cero
     print(names_lists[n - 1][second_item_idx])


print_second_name(names, 2)
# alexander

print_second_name(names, 4)
# IndexError: index out of bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a list of lists. If I get what you are going for,

```
L = [[1,2,3],[2,3],[5,6,7]] #Something like this
n = int(input("Enter a number"))
print("The value is: ", L[n-1][n-2]) #The reason why we use n-1 instead of n in because lists start with 0 index
```

or something like this